# requiredfield validator is preventing another form from submitting

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with many forms in panels and usercontrols, and a requiredfield validator I just added to one form is preventing all of my other forms from submitting. what's the rule that I'm not following?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using ValidationGroups?  Try assigning each control with a validation group as well as the validator that you want to use.  Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" ValidationGroup="Group1" ruant="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" ... ValidationGroup="Group1" />
```

Note, if a button doesn't specify a validation group it will validate all controls that aren't assigned to a validation group.

Comment: One opinion here. You should add ValidationGroup="Group1" to button not to textbox. If you are adding ValidationGroup="Group1" to text box, your buttomn will still be submitting data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting ValidationGroup property to a different value for each group of elements. Your validator's ValidationGroup must only be same with the control that submit its form.